# Heroku Everything Up-To-Date

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

So i've googled this error messages and went through the various stack overflow posts with regards to this. My issue came yesterday when the Dyn DNS were under a DDoS attack. Anyway the initial problem was that when i tried doing `git push heroku master` it constantly returned `everything up-to-date`

I tried everything i found in the various relevant stack overflow posts. From doing `git remote rm heroku` then adding it back, to checking out a new branch then doing `git push heroku <branch name>:master` but nothing worked.

After trying various other things i gave up and decided to simply delete my heroku app and try pushing all over.

Now the weird thing (which may just be my lack of understanding of how all these works) would be even after deleting my app and not creating a new one, when i run the command `git push heroku master` it still returns `everything up-to-date`. Why is that so when there is no longer any app there?

Additionally i have also tried `heroku create` before trying to push it and it returns `everything up-to-date` as well. I read that everything is up and running on heroku's side so i'm not quite sure what is the problem.

I can't seem to find any updated documentation on this issue as well so i'm hoping that someone can point me in the right direction or steps to take.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using force (worked for me when I had this problem in the past):

```
git push -f heroku
```

This will make Heroku to receive the files and build again, no matter if it thinks everything is up to date. (They even [recommend](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git#using-subversion-or-other-revision-control-systems) it)

Also, as you've created a new application, make sure you've set the remote to point to this new app:

heroku git:remote -a app_name

Comment: Okay i think setting the remote to point to this new app resolved the issue. Seemed to have overlooked that point. Thank you!